# Does Paterson adopt a backup strategy?

Tags: plot-explanation, paterson

In Jim Jarmusch's 2016 
 [Paterson](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5247022/),
 I didn't see this resolved. I thought of course you need 
 backups of your data. Except the film doesn't seem to say that.

- Paterson seems to resist publishing his poems
- He is opposed to owning a mobile phone
- He writes in paper notebooks; no word processors, recordings (we know guitar lessons are commonplace), or typewriters
- He recites other poets' work, but not his own to his wife

Is making backups against his methodology? Does Paterson
change and start backups? or is it fundamental and inconsistent with
his poetry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movie does not seem to show Paterson deciding on a back up methodology.
Maybe he will, because he respects Laura's opinions and ideas ; but it is not that important to him.

Why does Paterson writes poems?

If you think about that, you might understand why the topic of copies of the poems, is maybe not a major interest of the movie.