# Does Paterson grow in any way?

Tags: character, paterson

In the movie [Paterson](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5247022/?ref_=nm_flmg_dr_2), the titular character doesn't appear to me to change in any way during the movie. At the end of the film I was left thinking, "Well that was mildly interesting. What was the point of that?" Then I remembered the movie [Adaptation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0268126/?ref_=nv_sr_1).

In the movie Adaptation, Nicholas Cage plays a screenwriter (or 2) who at one point attends a screenwriting seminar. During the seminar, he tells the presenter that he wants to write a movie where the main character doesn't change. The presenter basically tells him, nobody wants to see that movie - there's no point in writing such a screenplay.

Did Jim Jaramuch make that movie in Paterson? If not, how did Paterson change or grow? Even more than just [whether he decided to make copies of his new poems](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75899/does-paterson-adopt-a-backup-strategy), did he change in any way at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From I[ndieWire's review](http://www.indiewire.com/2016/05/cannes-review-adam-driver-stars-in-jim-jarmuschs-paterson-his-most-intimate-film-290526/):

> Overall, however, “Paterson” belongs to its director, who excels at
>   **capturing the serenity of daily existence and what it means to find
>   deeper meaning in passing moments.**
>
> [...]
>
> But “Paterson” has too much clarity of mind to fall into a similar
>   category. The story builds to an accidental circumstance that, on the
>   surface, might not seem like a big deal — but in the context of
>   Paterson’s tiny universe, resonates with tragic connotations. **The
>   brilliantly cryptic finale explores what it means to work back from
>   personal setbacks to find a new source of inspiration.** It’s an apt
>   statement from Jarmusch, a filmmaker who continues to surprise and
>   innovate while remaining true to his singular voice, and who here
>   seems to have delivered its purest manifestation.

Comment: Cryptic I can agree with. Brilliant, I'm not so sure. I have to say, as an audience member, that didn't come through to me at all. Perhaps I'm just not smart enough to get it. But thanks for the insight!